# Why do you keep looping out "11111"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

aaa.py:

```
import subprocess

print(11111)
exp = 0
subprocess.run(['python', 'bbb.py'])

print(22222)
print(exp)
```

bbb.py

```
import aaa

print("hello world")
print("bbb.py :", aaa.exp)
aaa.exp += 1
```

Why does it keep getting stuck in a loop?

Comment: because bbb imports aaa on the first line.

Comment: `bbb` calls `aaa` which calls `bbb`, what did you expect?

Comment: What should I change to get the correct output ?

Comment: When you import a module, that **also** runs all of the top-level code in that module.  So when bbb imports aaa, all of the code in aaa runs, because it's all at the top level.

Comment: "What should I change to get the correct output?" How would we guess what is "the correct output"? [ask] and [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation creates a circular dependency between aaa.py and bbb.py, leading to an infinite loop. Let's break down what happens step by step:

```
1. aaa.py is executed.
2. import subprocess and print(11111) are executed.
3. exp is set to 0. subprocess.run(['python', 'bbb.py']) runs bbb.py.

Now, in bbb.py:
4. import aaa tries to import aaa.py again.
```

Here's the problem: when bbb.py imports aaa, it executes all the code in aaa.py again, including subprocess.run(['python', 'bbb.py']). This creates a loop where aaa.py spaws a subprocess that calls bbb.py, and bbb.py imports aaa.py, leading to an infinite loop.

**How to fix this:**

As both the programs are accessing and changing the value of exp, you can keep exp in a separate module and import that module in both aaa.py and bbb.py.

**exp.py**

```
exp = 0
```

**aaa.py**

```
import subprocess
import exp

print(11111)
subprocess.run(['python', 'bbb.py'])
print(22222)
print(exp.exp)
```

**bbb.py**

```
import exp

print("hello world")
print("bbb.py :", exp.exp)
exp.exp += 1
```

**Output**

```
11111
hello world
bbb.py : 0
22222
0
```

Comment: "aaa.py imports bbb.py" no, it spawns a process that runs bbb.py.

Comment: Makes sense, wrong choice of words. Thanks for pointing it out.